# Hiding Apex code outside managed package?

Tags: apex, package

my question in simple. Is there anyway to hide Apex code outside of a managed package? Let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off "View Setup and Configuration" for a user, which will disable the user's ability to see any setup option at all (including code). Other than that, managed packages are the only way to "hide" code from users that can otherwise see Setup.